# how to animate the timeline item that contains current date in ionic 3.x?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have timeline view in my app, and i want to animate the row of timeline that contains the current date. Here is my html code.

**workout.html**

```
<ion-content>

    <section id="cd-timeline" class="cd-container">
        <div *ngFor="let item of taskList; let i=index;" (click)="exerciseWatch(i)">
        <div class="cd-timeline-block">
            <!-- CUSTOMIZE YOUR STYLE USING DEFAULT IONIC VALUES SUCH AS POSITIVE, CALM, BALANCED,... -->
            <div class="cd-timeline-icon calm" text-center>
            <b>{{item.d}}/{{item.m}}</b>
            </div>
            <!-- CUSTOMIZE YOUR STYLE USING DEFAULT IONIC VALUES SUCH AS POSITIVE, CALM, BALANCED,... -->
            <div class="cd-timeline-content calm" padding>
            <h5 class="marginBottom0 marginTop0">{{item.name}}</h5>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </section>

</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a CSS class for your animation, let's say it's called `.animate-row`. Now you'll need something to compare the dates (if the date on your item is the same as the current date). Since i don't know how you're manipulating your DateTime i can't be more specific, but create a variable with current date (let's call it `currentDate`) as the same format as the date of the item you've looped over.

Then you'll use `[ngClass]` to dynamically set the animation to your item.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of taskList; let i=index;" (click)="exerciseWatch(i)" [ngClass]="{ 'animate-row': item.myItemDate == currentDate }">
  <!-- ALL YOUR HTML -->
</div>
```

ngClass will add a class to your HTML tag if a condition matchs, in tht case if your item date is the same as the current date.

Hope this helps.

### UPDATE

Made a [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/syn_ga/ktw4qnyx/1/) to show you how it works.

Comment: Understood, but where is the coding of animation has been written?

Comment: it can be in your `app.scss` file, then this animation will be in the global scope of your app. If you want the animation to be used only in the page you're animating just set the animation in your page .scss file, it's up to you

Comment: @MustafaLokhandwala made a jsfiddle to show you how it works and updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for you response man,
i have tried your solution, but again nothing is happened,
also i had a console log that dates are matches but the animation doesn't happened 


`---------Current Date--------2017-12-29
---------Item date----------2017-12-29
--------Item date----------2017-12-30
---------Item date----------2017-12-31
---------Item date----------2017-10-27
---------Item date----------2017-10-28
---------Item date----------2017-10-29
---------Item date----------2017-10-30
---------Item date----------2017-10-31`

Comment: Okk, Thanks a lot !
A little bit of changes are there but it works for me